# Stick the dataframe rows and column in one row+ replace the nan values with the day before or after

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df and I want to stick the values of it. At first I want to select the specific time,  and replace the Nan values with the same in the day before. Here is a simple example: I only want to choose the values in 2020, I want to stick its value based on the time, and also replace the nan value same as day before.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['day'] =[ '2020-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2020-01-02','2020-01-03', '2018-01-01', '2020-01-15','2020-03-01', '2020-02-01', '2017-01-01' ]
df['value_1'] = [ 1, np.nan, 32, 48, 5, -1, 5,10,2]
df['value_2'] = [ np.nan, 121, 23, 34, 15, 21, 15, 12, 39]
df
day     value_1     value_2
0   2020-01-01  1.0     NaN
1   2019-01-01  NaN     121.0
2   2020-01-02  32.0    23.0
3   2020-01-03  48.0    34.0
4   2018-01-01  5.0     15.0
5   2020-01-15  -1.0    21.0
6   2020-03-01  5.0     15.0
7   2020-02-01  10.0    12.0
8   2017-01-01  2.0     39.0
```

The output:

```
   _1   _2     _3   _4  _5  _6  _7  _8  _9    _10   _11 _12
0   1   121     1   23  48  34  -1  21  10      12  -1  21
```

I have tried to use the follwing code, but it does not solve my problem:

```
val_cols                    = df.filter(like='value_').columns

output             = (df.pivot('day', val_cols).groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x:x.ffill(axis=1).bfill(axis=1)).sort_index(axis=1, level=1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the output is supposed to be but i think this should do at least part of what you're trying to do

```py
df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df = df.sort_values(by=['day'])

filter_2020 = df['day'].dt.year == 2020
val_cols = df.filter(like='value_').columns

df.loc[filter_2020, val_cols] = df.loc[:,val_cols].ffill().loc[filter_2020]
print(df)

         day  value_1  value_2
8 2017-01-01      2.0     39.0
4 2018-01-01      5.0     15.0
1 2019-01-01      NaN    121.0
0 2020-01-01      1.0    121.0
2 2020-01-02     32.0     23.0
3 2020-01-03     48.0     34.0
5 2020-01-15     -1.0     21.0
7 2020-02-01     10.0     12.0
6 2020-03-01      5.0     15.0
```